# Separating out order dependent item performance

Tags: inference

I have performance measurements of items that are processed in some sequence, say *A*, *B*, *C*, *D*, *E*, etc.  I don't have any data on stand-alone item performance.

Each item appears zero or once in the each sequence, and there is a mixture of item orderings.

I suspect that the performance of *A* (say), is (mostly weakly) correlated with what appears before it, but not after it.

Which statistical test can I use to find the performance of individual items, and the impact other items have on their performance?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first sentence? Do you have performance for each item in the sequence? Why does the sequence matter? How are these items connected? How do they influence each other in a sequential manner?

Comment: Yes, I have performance for each item in the sequence. I suspect there might be orderings that minimise total time to process the sequence, or perhaps just slow pairing orders, e.g., processing *A* before *B* may be slower than processing *B* before *A*.

Comment: So you don't have any particular orderings in mind? And these orderings could be of arbitrary length?

Comment: In some cases there are dependencies, say *C* has to appear after *A*.  The length is arbitrary, but probably never longer than 100, but usually 10 to 20.

Comment: Then this just got a lot more complicated, since this would fall under exploratory analysis, statistical tests are out. You could use pattern matching to find such patterns, as for individual performance, impact and so, I don't know.

Comment: It is certainly a complicated problem.  I don't see how pattern matching would work, I don't see what length has to do with it, apart from increasing the computational cost.

Comment: Pattern matching would be used to find patterns in the first place, since you mentioned that they are of arbitrary length and you do not know them in advance.

Comment: Would it help if we assumed that the ordering effect got weaker the further apart the items (which might be true, it's a starting simplification)?  The simplest case would be to assume that an item is only affected by the immediately preceding item (so length is not an issue; not that I understand why length is an issue)

Comment: As it stands now this question is too abstract for me. Can you post some sample data in your question?